# Generating a datatable in JSF(or a page) from list of values retrieved from Javascript component

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a datatable defined like this:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 3px 3px;">
                    <fieldset>                          
                        <legend>SourcePublicationDates</legend>
                         <f:facet name="header" >
                                <h:outputText value="Add SourcePub date:"/>
                         </f:facet>    
                         <h:inputText id="sourcePublicationDate" value="#{dataEntry.sourcePublicationDate}">
                             <c:ajax event="keyup" />
                             <c:ajax event="focus" />   
                             <f:ajax execute="@this" render="sourcePublicationDate" />
                         </h:inputText>
                         <h:panelGroup style="padding-left: 3px;">
                                    <button class="manualContent" id="showSourcePublicationDateCalendar" type="button"><img src="/sourceNavigateWeb/resources/images/cal.gif"/></button>
                                    <div id="sourcePublicationDateCalendarContainer" />
                         </h:panelGroup>
                         <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{dataEntry.editSourcePubDates}">
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="dtSourcePubDate" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:dataTable id="dtSourcePubDate" value="#{dataEntry.sourcePubDates}" var="sourcePubDate">
                            <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header" >
                                <h:outputText value="Source Publication Dates:"/>
                            </f:facet>    
                            <h:inputText id="sourcePubDate" value="#{sourcePubDate}"/>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

And the value in this table comes from a multiselect calendar control which I ultimately get in javascript like below. I want to display each individual fullDate into a text box field part of the datatable which is ultimately bound to the jsf backing bean. How can I get the fullDate into the text box fields of datatable ? Or even in a non-editable form of the datatable ?

```
CalendarPopup.handleSelectForMultipleDates = function(type, args, obj, inputEl)
        {
        var arrDates = CalendarPopup.sourcePublicationDateCalendar.getSelectedDates();
        var length = arrDates.length;
        var i=0;
        while(i!=length)
        {
            var date = arrDates[i];
            var displayMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var displayYear = date.getFullYear();
            var displayDate = date.getDate();
            var fullDate = displayMonth + "/" displayDate + "/" + displayYear;
            i++;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Time for you to learn about Firebug and jQuery.  Neither tool will be required for this task, but both will make your life one trillion times easier.  I recommend using Firebug to inspect the DOM and jQuery to manipulate the DOM.  Firebug is handy because your JSF page will output html that looks much different than what you write in your JSP.  Firebug allows you to view it as it's delivered to the browser (which is what you'll have to manipulate).

Comment: How would you access individual rows of the datatable via jquery ?

Comment: You need to look at the HTML that is output by your JSP. It's impossible to answer your question without seeing your generated HTML.  It's also impossible to answer your question without knowing what you want to do.  "_Displaying each date into a text box field part of the datatable_" is not very specific.

Comment: The calendar control returns an list of dates like 04/10/2012,05/10/2013 .. this can be any number of selected dates, i want to put these dates back into the jsf datatable, how do I set each value from this array of dates into a row in the jsf datatable ?

Comment: @Phoenix I don't know if JSF components provide a javascript API to facilitate modifications directly on page. If you really want to make it in this way it will be hard but you can try to do all work by hand. I would prefer to use ajax (at the end of your current javascript function) to update data in your bean and then re-rendering the table via ajax also. I think that it will be the best approach. If you're interested in this second option, I can post some example code. Regards,